# Oracle - INSERT RANDOMLY generated English words as dummy data

Tags: sql, oracle, random

I have an Oracle database that could store millions of books. I dont have the data though!

How do I `insert` about a million dummy book titles in oracle?

Is there a function that lets you generate `random` English words? It's very important that they are English valid words.

Comment: Have you seen this `SELECT DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE FROM DUAL;` [Reference article](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-dbmsrandom-to-generate-text-and-date-values/6068749)

Comment: @bonCodigo I dont see anything for english words.

Comment: I suppose you can just download a wordlist and import them in your DB? eh?

Comment: +1 for your question. The part that you need gramatically correct English words is the most interesting slice of this question :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stored procedure to insert random strings. But the issue is, the strings generated might not be English words - that we can accept ;)

** PL/SQL ** - please recheck for syntax

```
create table allwords(words varchar(15));
-- insert all the English words that you could get from a **SCRABBLE** like website. :)

create table blabla( id int, name varchar(15) ) storage ( freelists 100 );

declare
  idNumber int;
  strName varchar(15);
  begin
    for i in 1 .. 100
     loop
       idNumber := dbms_random.random;
       strName := SELECT words FROM table ORDER BY dbms_random.value limit 1; 
       insert into blablah values(idNumber, strName);
     end loop;
     commit;
  end;
```

**UPDATED**

Please notice that if you can use a SCRABBLE like word list into a new table, then you do not need this stored procedure at all.
 The only use of this stored procedure is to get a random word/string and insert it into a respected table with many other columns together.